# Uploading videos and images using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

Please, I want to know why the first and the last endpoints in my app.js file and the rest are not working, especially the third one.

These are my files:

app.js

```
const  express = require('express');
const {uploadImage, uploadVideo} = require('./utils/multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const uploadSingleImageRouter = require('./routes/image/upload/single');
const uploadMultipleImageRouter = require('./routes/image/upload/multiple');
const uploadMultipleVideoRouter = require('./routes/video/upload/multiple');
const retrieveImages = require('./routes/image/retrieve/images');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routers

app.use('/api', uploadImage.single('image'), uploadSingleImageRouter, (error, req, res, next) =>{
    res.status(400).send({error: error.message});
});
app.use('/api', uploadImage.array('image', 10), uploadMultipleImageRouter, (error, req, res, next) =>{
    res.status(400).send({error: error.message});
});
app.use('/api', uploadVideo.single('video'), uploadMultipleVideoRouter, (error, req, res, next) =>{
    res.status(400).send({error: error.message});
});
app.use('/api', retrieveImages, (error, req, res, next) =>{
    res.status(400).send({error: error.message});
});

module.exports = app;
```

multer.js

```
const multer = require('multer');

//specify the storage engine

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, './public/imageUpload')
    },
    filename:function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
});

const storageVideo = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, './public/videoUpload')
    },
    filename:function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
});

// file validation

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype ===  'image/png'){
        cb(null,true);
    }else{
        cb({message: 'Unsupported File Format'}, false)
    }
};

const fileFilterVideo = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(file.mimetype === 'video/mp4'){
        cb(null,true);
    }else{
        cb({message: 'Unsupported File Format'}, false)
    }
};


const uploadImage = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {fileSize: 4096 * 4096},
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});

const uploadVideo = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: fileFilterVideo
});

module.exports = {uploadImage, uploadVideo};
```

single.js for uploading a single image router

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.json());

router.post("/uploadSingleImage", async(req, res)=>{
  res.send(req.file);
});

module.exports = router;
```

multiple.js for uploading multiple images

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.json());

router.post("/uploadImages", async(req, res)=>{
    res.send(req.files);
});

module.exports = router;
```

multiple.js for uploading a video

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.json());

router.post("/uploadVideo", async(req, res)=>{
    res.send(req.file);
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I make the post request to http://localhost:3000/api/uploadSingleImage on the postman, here is the result:

```
{
    "fieldname": "image",
    "originalname": "1330451179-origin.jpg",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
    "destination": "./public/imageUpload",
    "filename": "1652960485144-1330451179-origin.jpg",
    "path": "public\\imageUpload\\1652960485144-1330451179-origin.jpg",
    "size": 180426
}
```

For the post request on http://localhost:3000/api/uploadImages, when I'm uploading one image, here is the result:

```
[]
```

For two or more images, this is the result:

```
{
    "error": "Unexpected field"
}
```

And finally, for the post request on http://localhost:3000/api/uploadVideo, the result is:

```
{
    "error": "Unexpected field"
}
```

I need to know why for http://localhost:3000/api/uploadVideo, it displays an Unexpected Error, and for http://localhost:3000/api/uploadImages, it shows an empty array or unexpected Error.

I will be glad if Anybody can help me with it.
Thank you

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please how will I do that? I'm new to this platform